# Cannot get jOOQ CodeGen tool to work

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have tried multiple configurations and I am unable to get the **jOOQ codegen** tool to work. I have the 3 required jars, postgres driver and config xml in my classpath:

cmd:

```
java -cp jooq-codegen-3.11.0.jar org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool /postgres.xml
```

Error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jooq/meta/SchemaVersionProvider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have the 3 required jars, postgres driver and config xml in my classpath:

No, you don't :-) You only put the codegen library on the classpath, not its dependencies, nor the local path (where the XML file is located). Do this instead:

**Windows**

> java -cp jooq-3.11.0.jar;jooq-meta-3.11-0.jar;jooq-codegen-3.11.0.jar;. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool /postgres.xml

**Linux**

> java -cp jooq-3.11.0.jar:jooq-meta-3.11-0.jar:jooq-codegen-3.11.0.jar:. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool /postgres.xml

**Java 9+**

In Java 9, you may have to add the JAXB dependency manually by adding this to your java command

> --add-modules java.xml.bind

As documented in the manual:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration

**Related issues**:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7580
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7586

Comment: @dotnettech: Are you using Windows or Linux style shells? I've updated my answer with a Linux version. It should definitely work this way...

Comment: found a better ORM  - Sql2o

Comment: @dotnettech: Right... ;-) Good luck!